# Eclipse is not showing method parameters properly

Tags: eclipse

In my eclipse, when i check for method help with **ctrl+space** i see the method parameters are showing like strings, int as arguments. Not showing like, string name/int id .

**`getAttribute(String arg0)`**

How can i make the eclipse to show the method as **`getAttribute(String name)`**

This is really difficult to me identify which param i should pass fro a method.
Any idea, where should i set the settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem happens when eclipse can't find the source or attached Javadoc, since java argument names are usually not present in the `.class` files (it would only be present in debug, and not for the interfaces).

You can check if a source or a documentation is attached using the helper `F3`.

You can increase the timeout eclipse uses for fetching a parameter name from attached Javadoc in the settings.

You can also attach the corresponding documentation jar or source jar as a dependency in order to allow eclipse to look-up the corresponding source.

Comment: But in a big project, it  is always difficult to attach source of all releavant jars..But is that the only solution..?

Comment: @Ratha You can also import only the corresponding javadoc. But if you have a big project, then you certainly should consider using something like [*Maven*](http://maven.apache.org/).

Comment: @ zakinster, thanks for the quick reply. Yes im using maven to build my project and i set buildpath using maven repo. Anyway those repos contain only jars. How can i get javadoc out of those jars?

Comment: @Ratha It depends on what the jar is. If it's a *bytecode jar* containing only *.class*, then it doesn't contain any useful info (except in debug). If it's a *source jar* or a *javadoc jar* then it will contain what you need.